# Schedule a job to send mails

Tags: scheduled-job

I'm working on a class that sends emails to the campaign owners when a startdate is due. In this way i'm using the SingleEmailMessage to send the emails but i'm held in between on the realization phase I.E how to do it?

I'm not an expert in SFDC but just started working on it. considering my ERP experience we have tools to schedule a job and i assumed that this would be a similar way here but realized it is quite different. I suppose i need to extend the class for 'Schedulable'. Given that my class will not be triggered or called by an event or trigger how to achieve this to run the job daily on specific time?

Regards
PS

Comment: Yes you are correct you will have to implement a schedulable [How To](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_scheduling_1.htm)interface in a class in which you can write your logic. Now a class can be scheduled in two ways `1`: [Point and click](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_schedule_batch_apex.htm) '2' : By constructing a cron expression and executing it in dev console's execute anon block [Cron Expression Construction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)